# Passing PayPal Variables Through $_POST

Tags: php, paypal

I'm attempting to pass a $_POST variable through a PayPal payment, so I can verify the purchase of virtual currency on the other side.

My end goal is to have a field where the user can enter a custom dollar amount they would like to add to their account balance on my website. My current problem is that any user could just type out the exact URL of the page they are redirected to upon a successful PayPal payment that adds the amount to their account. I'm not sure what the best way is to tackle this issue, I've tried fiddling with IPN/PDT, Database cross-checking and webhooks, but at this point, I've moved five steps back instead of two steps forward. What would be the best way for me to move forward? Thank you in advance.

Side note: For the testing purposes so far, it's been a fixed rate of $10 that adds $10 to their account upon successful payment. I have a form submit that adds an "order request" database entry, before switching the header(Location) to the Paypal order. Upon Payment, they are taken to an "order success" page that checks the "order request" entry, if there, deletes it, and then adds a new entry to the "successful orders" database. If it's not there, it redirects to the home page. All pages besides the "successful orders" page checks the "order request" database to delete any entries with the user's username to prevent attempting to access the page directly from the site. The only issue, they could easily open a second tab while the PayPal payment page is still open, and type in the URL passing the check and adding to their account balance without paying. The same issue would occur with including a $_GET variable from PayPay upon successful payment. Someone could expose the $_GET and they would just add that to the URL. The same issue occurs with creating a $_SESSION before populating the PayPal transaction page. That's why I feel $_POST from PayPal directly would be most sufficient.